# Database design for polymorphic data

Tags: database-design, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an application that needs to log communications with users over several different mediums: Email, SMS, Voice, Website Announcements, etc.. in a traditional database.

I have considered 3 approaches to modeling these different types of data:

1. [Single Table Inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html):
   Store them all together in a single table (i.e., comm_message) with discriminator field of some sort to indicate the type of communications (e.g. message_type).  This means that some fields in the table won't be used for each type--and it means that the same message may be duplicated in several different rows in the table (if the message is sent via more than one medium).
2. Message "has" transports
   Have a message table (comm_message) and then transports table (comm_transports) with the various different mediums of communication.  A many-to-many relationship between messages and transports would mean one row for each message in the message table--but that row might have several different transports.  If additional specific information is needed for a particular transport, it could be in it's own table (i.e. comm_sms, comm_email, etc..) that is linked off the many-to-many table. I.e., a "has-a" approach.
3. [Class Table Inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html):
   Create a base message table (comm_message) and then another table for each medium with fields specific to it (inheritance).  My ORM (LLBLGen) would facilitate this approach by using shared PKs for the different tables.  In this approach there would be a row in the base table (comm_message), plus rows in each of the related tables for each transport (comm_email, comm_sms, etc.) but there would be no many-to-many relationship.  Rather the records across different tables would share the same PK (1-1).  This would be more of an "is-a" approach.

Context:  This is a medium sized application (around 100 tables) that I'll be maintaining for many years--so I'd like to get this "right".  I'll often need to present all the communications info together in the UI in a grid, reports, etc..

Which should I use?  Why?

Comment: It sounds like a message has a medium, but the medium isn't the message.  (Sorry, McLuhan).

Comment: Option 2 is the most scalable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) as composition lends itself well to *relational* databases.

Say you want to get all short messages:

```
SELECT * FROM Message INNER JOIN ShortMessage ON ShortMessage.message = Message.id
```

Say you want to get all short messages and emails:

```
SELECT * FROM Message 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ShortMessage ON ShortMessage.message = Message.id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Email ON Email.message = Message.id
```

This will effectively create a result set very much like what your first option is, with a lot of null fields.

So the basic idea here is that a message potentially *has a* email. Depending on whether or not you define `Email.message` to be `UNIQUE`, you can make sure there's at most one email corresponding to a message. This setup (like all alternatives you proposed) allows a single message to have multiple different transports, which is actually conceivable in the real world.

Advantages of this approach:

- (over 1 & 2) Your database is normalized, which usually gives you stuff for free

  - if you want to add new transport types without altering any existing tables (not something you want to do in a huge database)
  - You don't have to store loads of nulls
- (over 3) You can query all messages in one query, so you can get all messages to a specific recipient like so:

  ```
  SELECT IFNULL(Email.body, ShortMessage.body) as text FROM Message 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ShortMessage ON ShortMessage.message = Message.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Email ON Email.message = Message.id
    WHERE 
      Email.recepient = "john.doe@example.com" 
      OR ShortMessage.recipient = "01189998819991197253"
  ```

  And voilà, you've got yourself a list of all text ever sent to john doe.

However, if you're using an ORM, you might actually use the power to perform queries such as that. I am have no practical experience with C#, but from my understanding as an outsider, [Linq lends itself well to accessing relational databases for what they are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic12), instead of trying to shoehorn objects semantics onto records (which always makes you hit a very thick wall at some point down the road).

Comment: Thanks--I see this as a simplification of (2) with the drawback being its more difficult to get a list of transports for a given message.  Would you agree?  I don't see (2) as storing lots of NULLs as it splits type specific fields into their own tables as does your design.

Comment: @scotru You are right, I misread your second option. I'm still not sure I really understand it entirely how the `comm_transports` table is structured. Is its purpose to explicitly hold a mapping between a message and its transports? You can see that that's not fully normalized, as deleting the SMS of a message requires updating two tables instead of one as it would in the structure I propose. You have redundant information here. Getting this list by joining all the tables is maybe not the most comfortable way, but it is achievable with reasonable effort.

Comment: Yes, you raise good points.  I'm removing the relation between messages and transports and going with your suggested structure.  (though I'll still keep transports table around as it can store some useful metadata about the transports and also serve as the source for a list of available transports in the UI when I need it).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @scotru Most SQL flavors allow you to 1. add metadata to tables (at least with comments) and 2. to list all tables in a database. Consider using that to extract the list of all available transports.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use a database that natively supports inheritance, e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html).

Comment: Down voter please provide feedback